# Windows certutil exports with empty password but openssl pkcs12 fails

Tags: certificate, certutil

Here are the commands I follow to create a certificate and accept it usin Windows Server's CA Server.

```
certreq -new -f -q $answerFile.FullName $requestFile.FullName
certreq -submit -f -q -config $AuthorityCertificatesServer $requestFile.FullName $publicCertFile.FullName | Select-String 'Id. de solicitud: (\d+)' | ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value }
certutil -resubmit $ID_SOLICITUD
certreq -retrieve -f -q -config $AuthorityCertificatesServer $ID_SOLICITUD $publicCertFile.FullName
certreq -accept -f -q -user -config $AuthorityCertificatesServer $publicCertFile.FullName

certutil -f -user -exportPFX -p '' My $thumbprint $pfxCertFile.FullName NoRoot

openssl pkcs12 -in $pfxCertFile.FullName -clcerts -nokeys -out $DOMAIN.crt -passout pass: -passin pass:
openssl pkcs12 -in $pfxCertFile.FullName -nocerts -out $DOMAIN.key  -passout pass: -passin pass:
```

I have problems with the last 3.

`certutil -f -user -exportPFX -p '' My $thumbprint $pfxCertFile.FullName NoRoot`

This creates the pfx file (I assume with an empty password)

But these 2:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in $pfxCertFile.FullName -clcerts -nokeys -out $DOMAIN.crt -passout pass: -passin pass:
openssl pkcs12 -in $pfxCertFile.FullName -nocerts -out $DOMAIN.key  -passout pass: -passin pass:
```

Fail with

```
Mac verify error: invalid password?
New-WebHostingCertificate : Couldn't convert from PFX to Apache CRT/KEY
En línea: 1 Carácter: 1
+ New-WebHostingCertificate mywebsite.com
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,New-WebHostingCertificate
```

**Mac verify error: invalid password?**

Any idea why?

Comment: What is your OpenSSL version ?

Comment: OpenSSL 3.1.1 30 May 2023 (Library: OpenSSL 3.1.1 30 May 2023)

Comment: Could you try OpenSSL 1.x ?

Comment: Tried `OpenSSL 1.1.1w  11 Sep 2023` still got `Mac verify error: invalid password?`

Comment: Sorry, no more ideas.

Comment: Try adding empty quotes like `-passout pass: -passin pass:""`? I'm not sure `certutil` exports correctly with blank passwords (it's at least unable to import with blanks). Is there any reason not to just put an actual password in the script like `-exportPFX -p 'foo'`? `openssl` can strip it later with `-noDES`

Comment: Went with foo password and `-nodes`.